# How can I capture stdout and stderr output from a process with Haskell turtle?

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Turtle

runSh :: Text -> IO ()
runSh x = view $ inshell x empty

main :: IO ()
main = do
  runSh "echo 'abcxyz'"
```

I've got the above program which outputs:

```
Line "abcxyz"
```

Is there a way I can capture this text without being output to the shell's stdout?

Essentially, I'd like to run the process and get a `[Line]` value rather then a `()` value from the `IO` action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with [shellStrictWithErr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.4.4/docs/Turtle-Prelude.html#v:shellStrictWithErr).

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Turtle (empty, shellStrictWithErr, ExitCode)
import Data.Text (Text)

runSh :: Text -> IO (ExitCode, Text, Text)
runSh x' = shellStrictWithErr x' empty

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (e, v, v') <- runSh "ls"
  print e
  print v
  print v'
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me: "Module ‘Turtle’ does not export ‘shellStrictWithErr’". Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps a older / newer version of Turtle?